# Solve $I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\frac{y^2}{x^2}}dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I tried to solve this integral by using polar coordinate system, but it becomes harder:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\frac{y^2}{x^2}}dxdy$$
After transformation
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan{(\tan^2\theta)}\sin\theta \cos\theta d\theta\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{cos\theta}}r^2\arctan{(r)}dr$$
And after IBP, $$\int r^2\arctan{(r)}dr=\frac{1}{6}\left(2r^3\arctan(r)-r^2+\ln(r^2+1)\right)$$ and replace upper and lower limits, it becomes a mess.
Did I misdirect? Need some help from everyone, thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integrand function is not symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$, so $I$ is not two times the integral over the triangle $\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}$.
On the other hand, note that
$$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\,dydx\\
&\qquad+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\,dxdy\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\right)dydx.
\end{align*}$$
Now recall that $\arctan(t)+\arctan(1/t)=\pi/2$ for $t>0$, therefore
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dydx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\left(\int_{0}^{1/\cos(\theta)}r^2\arctan(r)\,dr\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\left[\frac{1}{6}\left(2r^3\arctan(r)-r^2+\ln(r^2+1)\right)\right]_{0}^{1/\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{12}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{t^3}+2\arctan(t)-\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{48}\left(8\ln(2)-7\ln(3)+8\sqrt{2}\arctan(\sqrt{2})-2\pi\right)
\end{align*}$$
where $t=1/\cos(\theta)$.

For the second part, we have also another way which seems to be easier
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dydx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}r^2\arctan(r)\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta\right)\,dr\\
&\qquad+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}r^2\arctan(r)\left(\int_{\arccos(1/r)}^{\pi/4}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta\right)\,dr\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}r^2\arctan(r)\left[-\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2}\right]_{0}^{\pi/4}\,dr+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}r^2\arctan(r)\left[-\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2}\right]_{\arccos(1/r)}^{\pi/4}\,dr\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_{0}^{1}r^2\arctan(r)\,dr+\frac{\pi}{8}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(r)\left(2-r^2\right)\,dr\\
&=\frac{\pi}{48}\left(8\ln(2)-7\ln(3)+8\sqrt{2}\arctan(\sqrt{2})-2\pi\right).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: In fact, i can do it from here, just struggle at the beginning, thank you so much.